# ¿Cómo pedir la opinión de alguien?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

¿Cómo se pide la opinión de alguien sobre un tema o actividad?

**Por ejemplo, en ingles se dice:**

> What do you think about __________?

Comment: ¿Qué se te opina de X?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use the following:

> ¿Qué [opinas](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=opinar) (acerca) de *_*_?
>
> ¿Qué [piensas](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=pensar) (acerca) de *_*_?
>
> ¿Cuál es tu opinión (acerca) de *_*_?

"acerca" can be ommited.

Examples:

> ¿Qué opinas **acerca de** la liberacion femenina?
>
> ¿Qué piensas **de** la gente que trabaja en la noche?
>
> ¿Cuál es tu opinión **acerca de** las empresas que permiten trabajar desde casa?

You can also replace "[acerca de](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=acerca)" with "[sobre](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sobre)":

> ¿Qué opinas **sobre** la liberacion femenina?
>
> ¿Qué piensas **sobre** la gente que trabaja en la noche?
>
> ¿Cuál es tu opinión **sobre** las empresas que permiten trabajar desde casa?

Answer (score 2):

In Spain at least we usually use

> ¿cómo lo ves?

Answer (score 1):

I hear and use frequently "¿Qué te parece si ..." (South, Central American; Spanish)

Comment: This is not very correct, the word "si" means "if", si it makes it very specific.

Answer (score -4):

I hear:

> ¿Tú crees?

All the time meaning:

> What's your opinion?
>
> What would you do if you were me?

Comment: **¿Tú crees?** does not mean that. It means "Do you believe it?"

Comment: @Flimzy He visto en realidad variadas ocasiones en donde *¿Tú crees?* se escribe como *Do you think so?* No sé a qué se debe la traducción pero para mí es simplemente como lo dices, solo que no lo usan de esa manera.